# What is the most efficient way to draw text in a layer-backed NSView on the mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, core-animation, nsview

I am looking for an efficient way to draw text in a layer backed `NSView` as I am trying to keep frame-per-second (fps) high inside an `NSScrollView`.

My understanding is as follows: layer-backed `NSView` is managed by `AppKit` to give you good performance BUT you can't add your own layers (else it would not be managed by `AppKit` anymore).

You can use the `drawRect` path OR `updateLayer` path for "drawing" commands. Which is the more efficient path to go? If `updateLayer` is more efficient then how does one go about drawing text within this overridden function?